# How to get dotted line to list of figures in classicthesis?

Tags: classicthesis

My list of algorithms aligns the page numbers at the right margin and fills the space between the caption and the number with dots. However the list of tables, listings and figures don't do this. How can I enable this for all of them?

[image]

I use classicthesis.sty version 2012/08/12 v4.1. I also tried this with the one from texlive 2017 but there I don't even get the dots for the algorithms and the header "List of Algorithms" is formatted incorrectly.

Excerpt from `Contents.tex`:

```
%*******************************************************
% List of Tables
%*******************************************************
\newpage
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\pdfbookmark[1]{\listtablename}{lot}
\listoftables
\vspace*{8ex}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 %  List of Listings
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\clearpage
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\pdfbookmark[1]{\lstlistlistingname}{lol}
\lstlistoflistings   %-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   List of Algorithms   %-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\let\oldnumberline\numberline
\renewcommand{\numberline}{Algorithm~\oldnumberline}
\pdfbookmark[1]{List of Algorithms}{loa}
\listofalgorithms
```

I would like to provide an MWE but I don't know where to start as the classicthesis template is massive.

Comment: Classicthesis follows Bringhurst's idea that page numbers aren't to be summed up, so they don't need to be aligned.

Answer (score -1):

It was `\PassOptionsToPackage{dottedtoc}{classicthesis}`.

The list of Algoriths is dotted without this option because it is added in `Contents.tex`.